How to compute multiple matrix exponentials efficiently?
I have a question regarding the efficient computation of multiple matrix exponentials:
Let $G \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ (in my case $n \approx 1000$) be fixed. Assume we have an equidistant time grid $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \dots t_N = T$, width given width $h$. Hence $t_i = h i$ for $i = 0,\dots,N$.
Goal: Compute $e^{t_i G}$ efficiently for all $i = 0,\dots,N$.
Calculating a single $e^{t_i G}$ takes few seconds (I use the expm function from the scipy library) but doing this for the entire grid takes some time.
My first thought was the following: Calculate $e^{hG}$ once and then use
$$
e^{t_i G} = (e^{hG})^i
$$
Indeed, this is way faster. However, the errors for the repeated matrix multiplication (I just did it naively, maybe there is a "better", less error prone, matrix multiplication) suggested by the above formula get large really quickly, hence I cannot use the formula above and really have to compute each exponential individually.
Question: Is there another way, where I can exploit the above formula to get a faster overall evaluation of all $e^{t_i G}$?
Any idea is greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

this is what comes to mind:  https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~misha/ReadingSeminar/Papers/Moler03.pdf  I see, original article with those 122 references up to top of page 37,  then more recent developments and references 123-158

Thanks, for the comment. I also tried an ODE approach for now. Using a scipy ODE solver using Runge Kutta I get a now satisfactory result since this allows to compute the solution over any desired time grid simultaneously in a relatively quick amount of time.

Do you actually need the matrices $e^{t_iG}$ or is it enough be able to compute the action $y = e^{t_iG}x$ for arbitrary $x$? Do your matrices $G$ have any special properties that could be exploited?

Yes, actually I need $(e^{t_0 G}x,\dots,e^{t_NG}x)$ for some special $x$ and the matrix is "rather sparse".

If you only need this for a few $x$ then solving the ODE with $x$ as the initial condition will likely be the easiest and fastest. If the system isn't too stiff, you can even take larger time steps and interpolate the solution back to the original grid ${t_i}$

Thanks, up until now, solving the IVP seems really like the fastest solution so far.
